# Run socket Server in a ionic1 application

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic-v1

Here is the requirement:

> Start a socket server in the app which will receive messages from another app running in the same device.

Here is the stack:

- Ionic1/cordova
- Angular1
- cordova plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcpserver

Using the chrome's tcpServer plugin, I ended this code:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        var tcpServer = window.chrome && window.chrome.sockets &&
            window.chrome.sockets.tcpServer;

        if(tcpServer) {  
            console.log('LOG tcpServer present')
            tcpServer.create({}, function (createInfo) {
                var serverSocketId = createInfo.socketId;
                console.log('LOG', 'serverSocketId', serverSocketId)
                if (serverSocketId > 0) {
                    tcpServer.listen(serverSocketId, '0.0.0.0', 8080, 50, function(resultCode) {
                        console.log('LOG', 'listening', resultCode)
                    });
                } else {
                  console.log('LOG', 'Unable to create socket');
                }

            });
        } else {
            console.log('LOG', 'missing chrome.sockets.tcpServer')
        }
    });
})
```

And the result of this code is:

```
LOG tcpServer present
LOG serverSocketId 0
LOG Unable to create socket
```

Given that I've no experience in ionic1/iOS:

- Is this my option to create this socket server?
- `0` means that the create method failed. What could I be doing wrong here?
- Do I need some special permission in iOS to perform those actions? (Similar to Android)
- I couldn't find resources/examples to help me doing this. Where should I search?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't see how this is going to work; Only one app can be in the foreground at a time on iOS, so when your app is running the other app can't be sending data to it and when the other app is running your app can't be listening on a socket.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your comment. What about background service? Anyway, I thought exactly what you just said but couldn't find any documentation about it to confirm it.

Comment: There are a few different background modes on iOS but listening on a socket isn't one of them

Comment: I had similar requirement But I use the signalr or socket.io technology to handle the  communication between 2 apps in the same phone and/or different phones.  To use the signalr or socket.io asynchronized socket connection, you need an additional Windows Pc or linux pc.